# react-google-recaptcha issue when changing pages

Tags: reactjs, recaptcha

Added google-recaptcha to my app everything working great,
The only issue is that when I change pages/components the badge on the right side of the screen disappears (but still working in the background).
By the way if I reload the page with f5 it appears again!

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your environment, for React 18 in strict mode, it seems to be a known issue with this library.
Here is the actual issue in the [library's repository](https://github.com/dozoisch/react-google-recaptcha/issues/250)

Apparently, it is only an issue in the development mode. By removing
`<React.StrictMode>` from the `index.js` now my component is rerendering.

Again, this solution would depend on the project and the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<React.StrictMode>` because it does not work in strict mode index.js